# Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount. Source height is 0. HTML5 canvas and react

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a **base64 image uri** into a html5 canvas.
Below is the code i used:

```
let drawer = (image) = {
    image.onload = ()=>{shadowCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)}

    let imageData = shadowCtx.getImageData(0, 0,  
        shadowCanvas.width,shadowCanvas.height),
        data = imageData.data
}
```

I am passing **image** as an arg to the function containing above snippet.
Image is initialized as:

```
loadImg = (url) => {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    return image;
}
```

I am stuck on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the codepen for whole js file:https://codepen.io/ashish-kafle/pen/xMZZXP?editors=0010

Comment: Where is `image` coming from in the first snippet? Because the second one is a function that will load the image and having `onload` applied to it after makes little sense.

Comment: `image` is the data that i get from a canvas that is rendered on html document. Then i am calling a seperate function passing `image.data` as argument for post processing on the pixels.